# Cocoa check if a keyboard shortcut is in use

Tags: cocoa, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a user specified global hotkey and want to check and make sure it's not going to collide with other applications. Is there any API that can ask other applications for their shortcuts or am I stuck manually checking if the selected shortcut is a common one (Cmd+v, Cmd+C etc.)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask the responder chain, in particular [NSResponder tryToPerform:with:] method will return if anything handles your action. Don't worry about what other apps are doing, just check if the user's shortcut is already in use.

tryToPerform:with:
Attempts to perform the action indicated method with a specified argument.

- (BOOL)tryToPerform:(SEL)anAction with:(id)anObject
  Parameters
  anAction
  The selector identifying the action method.
  anObject
  The object to use as the sole argument of the action method.
  Return Value
  Returns NO if no responder is found that responds to anAction, YES otherwise.

Discussion
If the receiver responds to anAction, it invokes the method with anObject as the argument and returns YES. If the receiver doesn’t respond, it sends this message to its next responder with the same selector and object.

Availability
Available in OS X v10.0 and later.
See Also
– doCommandBySelector:
sendAction:to:from: (NSApplication)
Declared In
NSResponder.h

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsresponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/tryToPerform:with: